# How to prevent users from manipulating the 'data:' part of the AJAX Code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

First of all, I know that the data sent to the server will not be manipulated (I tried and I was not able to manipulate data sent to the server by simply manipulating data in the `data:` part of the AJAX Request code.). Well, I am not sure about this.

For example, Let's take the following AJAX code into consideration.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'some/url',
    type: 'POST',
    data:{
        'user_id': '6',
        'data_key': 'data_value'
    },
    success:{ // Do Something },
    error: { // Do Something }
});
```

Now, What if some random user manipulates the `user_id` using **inspect element** or **firebug** or something like that. What actually happens then?

I tried and I was not able to do this. Why?

Comment: That’s what server side validation is for.

Comment: Your ajax requests are public, you can hit it with postman or any other tool. If they manipulate it, you need to make sure on server side to validate.

Comment: There's really nothing you can do to prevent this on the client-side. Your server-side code can implement checks on the data and verification of the client but that's about it

Comment: As a general rule, you never trust user. You cannot do much to prevent them from entering dangerous input. You must do data validation in the backend.

Comment: Have a look here for some excellent references ~ https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Attack

Comment: Server should never trust client.

Comment: You don't worry about ***if*** or ***how*** users will modify data sent to your server you ***must always expect that they will***

Answer (score 2):

You can never rely on input that comes from the client. It would be very easy for someone to simply open the console and write:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'some/url',
    type: 'POST',
    data:{
        'user_id': '999',
        'data_key': "something you weren't expecting"
    },
    success:{ // Do Something },
    error: { // Do Something }
});
```

Or catch the packet and edit it using any tool such as [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)